# Publication of Private Address

Tags: privacy, address

I work in an R&D department at an international company and since a few years I file patents on a regular basis.

Due to private reasons I and my wife seriously took care not to publish our private postal address on any website. This worked well until I discovered via google that my private postal address is published online along with my patents.

To clarify: I am not concerned that my private postal address is known to the patent office, or even in print somewhere. But I don't want it to be searchable, since this way anybody can type my name into google, get my address, and drive to our house (and kids).

The German patent office realised this problem in 2010 and changed the "Private Address"-Field to "Address" ([link](https://www.dpma.de/docs/dpma/mitteilungen/mitteilungen_der_praesidentin_2010.pdf)), however, most of our patents are at least EU & US wide.

I talked to our patent lawyer, but he basically said he can't do anything about it.

So my question is:

- Can I avoid publishing my private address for new patent applications and can I change my address for existing patents?
- May I legally use a post-office box instead?
- How would you handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Can I avoid publishing my private address for new patent applications and can I change my address for existing patents?**

Just give a business address on new cases. In most countries, that'll be fine.

Indeed it's quite common for the address of inventors to be the address of the applicant. In this way, mail for the inventors (such as the forms the EPO frustratingly insists on sending to inventors) actually goes to the applicant for the in-house patent team to deal with.

As for existing patents, you could have your address updated in the records of each patent office. However, it would retrospectively change the publications already released which show your address.

**May I legally use a post-office box instead?**

In some countries, sure.

However, for some countries there is an obligation to include a physical residential address. For example, in the US, 37 CFR 1.63(b)(2) provides that an inventor's oath must include:

> A mailing address where the inventor customarily receives mail, and residence, if an inventor lives at a location which is different from where the inventor customarily receives mail, for each inventor.

In such cases, a post office box would not be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the CFR text is as Maca quotes. However, the USPTO declaration form https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/documents/sb0001.pdf first asks for residence city state and country and then asks for mailing address. If your mailing address is a PO Box, there is actually no place on the form to put the street and address.